# W2012R2 RDP Server: the number of connections to this computer is limited and all connections are in use right now

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

Recently, the following message has started appearing for clients attempting to connect to our Windows 2012 R2 RDP Server:

```
the number of connections to this computer is limited and all connections are in use right now. 
Try connecting later or contact your system administrator.
```

There are only about 25 licensed users and no other network services running on this server.

I am having the hardest time finding actual, useful information and help on this matter, so I hope someone here can offer some insight and suggestions.

Comment: You need to check the session limits on the server. These can be configured directly or via GPO.

Comment: The connection limit is set to 999999 (unlimited)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but did you ever find an answer to this? Having the same problem suddenly on a 2012 R2 RDSH with unlimited connections configured. 110 users. Never had this problem until this week, been in production for 6 years.

Comment: It turned out that port 3389 was directly exposed to the internet via NAT. Horrific, I know, but at least the reason for the error was a huge number of unwanted connection attempts on the port. I ended up plugging the port on the firewall, and I also had to change RDP port on the server to something else - 3388 or somesuch as the server seemed to hang on to its refusal to allow access on 3389. It's a long time ago, so I only remember the few little bits.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/501250)

Comment: It wouldn't let me comment, so I had to add an answer instead.